# SQL Server: The total size of an index or primary key cannot exceed 900 bytes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to put an index on a column that will hold URLs. Since the maximum length of a URL an be over 2000 characters long I set the data type to NVARCHAR(3000). When I did this I got the error  `The total size of an index or primary key cannot exceed 900 bytes`. Since I may need to search for records by URL i will need an index on my URL Column. Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: That really doesn't sound very efficient to me.  In fact it sounds like a complete nightmare for the DB engine to manage.  Have you established that you *do* need to search by URL, and that this search is going to be slow?  Text search can be pretty quick you know.  There's also the possibility you can break up the URL into bits, index only one of those bits (the one that varies most) and then relate the index part to the whole url.  In short there are lots of possible strategies here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a computed column for the checksum of the URL and then use the checksum in the query.  Checksums will not be unique, but it will quickly narrow down the number of possible matches.

First, add a computed column to your table, like this:

```
Alter Table YourTableName Add URL_HASH As CheckSum(URL)
```

Now index the column like this:

```
Create Index idx_YourTableName_URL_HASH On YourTableName(URL_HASH)
```

Now you can write a query that will do an index seek to find the row you are looking for:

```
Select URL
From   YourTableName
Where  URL_HASH = CheckSum(N'google.com')
       And URL = 'google.com'
```

This method should work very well for exact matches.  If you want partial matches, you're better off using the full text search functionality.

Comment: Thanks we decided to implement this.

Comment: Hi G Mastros. Thanks for your answer. I have Varbinary column that holds a lot of data. This column can be null and I have query which looks for records where this column is not null. Your checksum approach seems very useful in this case as well. I checked that checksum for nullable column is 2147483647. Although it may work but It seems weird to hard-code this number in the queries. Will this number be this same when we migrate to other version of SqlServer? I did shoot myself in the foot once using GetHashCode method in C# and it ended up it returns different value depends on the OS.

Comment: I don't really know for sure.  However, instead of hardcoding the number you could use "checksum(Convert(varbinary, null))".  Then, if the value changes with db version, you'll still be protected.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Full Text search is what you'll probably want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

You have to jump through some minor hoops with setting it up vs a simple index but it shouldn't be super hard.