# How to hash a URL quickly

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, hash

I have a unique situation where I need to produce hashes on the fly. Here is my situation. This question is related to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801282/sql-server-the-total-size-of-an-index-or-primary-key-cannot-exceed-900-bytes). I need to store a many urls in the database which need to be indexed. A URL can be over 2000 characters long. The database complains that a string over 900 bytes cannot be indexed. My solution is to hash the URL using MD5 or SHA256. I am not sure which hashing algorithm to use. Here are my requirements

- Shortest character length with minimal collision
- Needs to be very **fast**. I will be hashing the referurl on every page request
- **Collisions** need to be minimized since I may have millions of urls in the database

I am not worried about security. I am worried about character length, speed, and collisions. Anyone know of a good algorithm for this?

Comment: What are you then doing with the URLs?

Comment: Git is using SHA1 which hashes a great deal more data than simple urls. I'd go with SHA1, you don't really need SHA2.

Comment: The urls will be stored in the database without an index. I will use the has value to search for a given url. But the url will be used to produce links on a given webpage.

Comment: "Shortest character length with minimal collision" – this doesn't really make sense as a requirement. Assuming a "perfect" hash function, the probability of collision will be inversely proportional to the hash length. You need to plug the hash length and how many total URLs you expect to have in your database into the birthday paradox formula to get a collision probability and make a judgement call as to whether that's "low enough".

Comment: Furthermore, I'm guessing that making a hash function closer to "perfect" given a hash size requires making the algorithm more complex. If your database can index 900 bytes, you might be able to gain a low risk of collision with high performance by using your own trivial hash function that outputs a 900-byte hash. (By, say, taking every 900 bytes of the URL and xoring them together.) Of course this will impact read performance because the database will have to hash said 900 bytes on every index lookup, so that's another tradeoff you have to consider.

Comment: Why would you be stuck between MD5 and SHA-256? SHA-1 is the same speed as MD5 in the .NET framework, but it's more secure, and requires only slightly more storage space.

Comment: @Inerdia Perfect hashes don't apply here, since the dataset is not known upfront and static. The tradeoff is a perfectly reasonable one: shorter hashes mean higher probability of collision.

Comment: You say you need fast, but it sounds like you're fetching webpages. Any network round trip is going to be orders of magnitude slower than hashing a short string.

Comment: @Nick "Perfect" might be the wrong term then – apparently I've encountered a terminology collision. "Ideal" might be a better word; I meant such a hash function that for any set of distinct inputs generates uniformly distributed hash values.

Comment: @Inerdia Fair enough. Any secure hash function is indistinguishable from an ideal one, though, and would thus make a reasonable choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I wouldn't use any of the cryptographic hash functions (i.e. MD5, SHA), since they were designed with security in mind: They mainly want to make it as hard as possible to finde two different strings with the same hash. I think this wouldn't be a problem in your case. (the possibility of *random* collisions is inherent to hashing, of course)

I'd **strongly not suggest** to use `String.GetHashCode()`, since the implementation is not known and MSDN says that it might vary between different versions of the framework. Even the results between x86 and x64 versions may be different. So you'll get into troubles when trying to access the same database using a newer (or different) version of the .NET framework.

I found the algorithm for the Java implementation of `hashCode` on Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29)), it seems quite easy to implement. Even a straightforward implementation would be faster than an implementation of MD5 or SHA imo. You could also use `long` values which reduces the probability of collisions.

There is also a short analysis of the .NET `GetHashCode` implementation [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gethashcode) (not the algorithm itself but some implementation details), you could also use this one I guess. (or try to implement the Java version in a similar way ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng` class, I would suggest. It's 160 bits or 20 bytes long, so that should definitely be small enough. If you need it to be a string, it will only require 40 characters, so that should suit your needs well. It should also be fast enough, and as far as I know, no collisions have yet been found.

Comment: Surely 160 bits would be 28 characters in base64 encoding? Even using hexdecimal its still only 40 characters (4 bits per character).

Comment: @Chris Try & see `Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[20]).Length`

Comment: @Chris: My math is a bit off :) And I was actually thinking hexadecimal, since I don't know much about the site. They may need to be URL-friendly. But again, that's only if it needs to be a string. BINARY() would be better.

Comment: @L.B.: I was right. My first question was rhetorical though rather than a genuine request for information. It seems less confrontational to me to phrase things this way rather than as "You're wrong. It would be 28/40 bytes". It is an excellent example of how easy it is to check these thinsg though. Especially if you have something like LinqPad that can execute single lines of code like that without needing to put it in any kind of framework. :)

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, the `SHA1Cng` implementation is generally the fastest. `SHA1Managed` is the slowest, and `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` is pretty much the same as `SHA1Cng` (though I get about a 1% improved performance on `SHA1Cng`). Tested this using 1KB plaintexts on a Core i5 processor.

Comment: @Chris I wrote `Try & see` just to avoid to write `you are wrong`. It seems that you haven't made a little check `Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[20]).Length`  before writing your comment.  
Even if you were right `Surely 160 bits would be 28 characters in base64 encoding? Even using hexdecimal its still only 40 characters` smells like sarcasm not rhetoric

Comment: @L.B.: Perhaps you're right. I guess I am always wary of stating things outright too because I am aware I may have missed something myself. Sometimes I make comments like that (though perhaps a little less easy to check) and have people say that no in fact I am wrong. Last thing I want is to state something as a fact that turns out to be wrong and people believe because I sound authoritative. :) Probably rather off topic and not something to worry about here though. :)

Answer (score 0):

<del>I'd personally use [String.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx). This is the basic hash function. I honestly have no idea how it performs compared to other implementations but it should be fine.</del>

Either of the two hashing functions that you name should be quick enough that you won't notice much difference between them. Unless this site requires ultra-high performance I would not worry too much about them. I'd personally probably go for MD5. This can be formatted as a string as hexdecimal in 64 characters or as a base 64 string in 44 characters.

The reason I'd go for MD5 is because you are very unlikely to run into collisions and even if you do you can structure your queries with "where urlhash = @hash and url = @url". The database engine should work out that one is indexed and the other isn't and use that information to do a sensible search.

If there are colisions the indexed scan on urlhash will return a handful of results which will be easy to do text comparisons on to get the right one. This is unlikely to be relevant very often though. You've pretty low chances of getting collisions this way.

Comment: This probably should not be used as the implementation of this function could change from version to version of the .Net Framework (as specifically pointed out in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

a quick one :

```
URLString.GetHashCode().ToString("x")
```

Answer (score 0):

While both MD5 and SHA1 have been proved ineffective where collision prevention is essential I suspect for your application either would be sufficient. I don't know for sure but I suspect that MD5 would be the simpler and quicker of the two algorithms.

Comment: Surprise! In real-world tests, MD5 and SHA-1 are of the same speed in the .NET framework.

Comment: SHA1 has known weaknesses, but isn't broken. It'd be wise to treat it as broken, though, when security is required.

Answer (score 0):

Reflected source code of GetHashCode function in .net 4.0

```
public override unsafe int GetHashCode()
{
    fixed (char* str = ((char*) this))
    {
        char* chPtr = str;
        int num = 0x15051505;
        int num2 = num;
        int* numPtr = (int*) chPtr;
        for (int i = this.Length; i > 0; i -= 4)
        {
            num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
            if (i <= 2)
            {
                break;
            }
            num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
            numPtr += 2;
        }
        return (num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
    }
}
```

There was O(n) simple operations(+, <<, ^) and one multiplication. So this is very fast.

I've tested this function on 3 mln DB contains strings lengths up to 256 characters and about 97% of strings has no collision. (Maximum 5 strings have the same hash)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the following project:

[CMPH - C Minimal Perfect Hashing Library](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/)

And check out the following hot topics listing for perfect hashes:

[Hottest 'perfect-hash' Answers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perfect-hash/hot)

You could also consider using a full text index in SQL rather than hashing:

[CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)